# Unable to get a UI Element i.e Registration Number from the website

Tags: uipath, uipath-studio, uipath-activity

I'm trying to get a registration number from a website, but it is throwing an error "Couldn't find the UI element corresponding to this selector".

The closest match with 95% is the registration number that I'm looking for. How do I get it?

[Error Message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/efDXL.png)

Answer (score 0):

Change the selector value for `aaname` from

`aaname='00450234.opens in a new window'`

to

`aaname='*opens in a new window'`

This will resolve the issue by allowing the value of `aaname` to match any value so long as it ends in "opens in a new window" by replacing the numeric part with a wildcard.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. 

I tried going with the above approach, however, now it is matching the 2nd closest match which is - 

[86%] <webctrl aaname='www.russellscanlan.comwww dot russellscanlan dot com. opens in a new window' name='false' parentid='who-is-this-details-content' tag='A'/> 

and not 

[95%] <webctrl aaname='01179331. opens in a new window' name='false' parentid='who-is-this-details-content' tag='A'/>

Comment: If you set the selector to be `<webctrl aaname='*opens in a new window' name='false' parentid='who-is-this-details-content' tag='A'/>` then it will match with all of the options you have mentioned so far